# Getting a specific string from job log

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need some help. I'm a noob in Jenkins and Groovy.

How to get a specific string from the log containing a certain word and print?

```
def log = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName
('deploy/my_deploy').getBuildByNumber(checkjob.getNumber()).log
        if (log.contains("Word")) {println log}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "log" type Jenkins sends back, but for instance you can try the findAll method, like this :

```
def log = [ "First line", "Second line", "End of log"]
println log.findAll { line -> line.contains("line") }

>>> [First line, Second line]
```

Which iterates through the string list (log), and for every line in it, take it if the condition ( line.containts("line") ) is true